# Problem Publishing Silverlight Application LocalHost

Tags: silverlight-3.0, uri, localhost

I am trying to publish my SilverLight application to the web and I keep getting "An error occurred while trying to make a request to URI "http://localhost:2898....".

I've changed the ServiceReferences.ClientConfig to point to the web address but the app still keeps on trying to connect to localhost.

I've opened the application in FireFox and took a look at the firebug log and it says: -

clientaccesspolicy.xml 404 Not Found   localhost:2898

crossdomain.xml 404 Not Found  localhost:2898.

The silverlight app is accessing the web service in the same domain, I just don't know why it is still trying to connect to localhost.

Any help appreciated.

Steve

Comment: What do you mean by "trying to publish"? What exactly are you trying to do and how are you trying to do it?

Comment: i think he's trying to publish an asp website that has a silverlight applicated nested in it, hence u publish the asp site to IIS, are you publishing to ur local pc? that may be why its resolving ur ip to localhost

Answer (score 0):

Two things come to mind, but check your "c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts" file and make sure ure local computer name or ip isnt mapped to localhost or the network machine isnt mapped to localhost for whatever strange reason.

Is the Silverlight app And WCF Service hosted on your localmachine, or are you accessing a server on your local network?

Answer (score 0):

Just open the `hosts` file (`C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc`) and uncomment the following line (remove # from the beginning of the line): `127.0.0.1       localhost`

Then save it, it should work.